# DoS in Sleep function PLSQL

Tags: plsql, dos

How to avoid DoS attack in the below case?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION slow_function (
  p_in INT
AS
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOCK.sleep(p_in);
END;
)
```

Comment: I don't think a single PL/SQL function with a sleep inside it are grounds for a denial of service attack? Wouldn't the sleep only affect the current session? If so, how are you managing sessions? How are you exposing this function?

Comment: Lock down access to that function (or better still, don't expose it to your users).

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP does not use any significant resources.  There is nothing specific to that function that would enable a denial of service attack.  On the contrary, that is probably one of the safest functions anybody could execute.

To demonstrate this, I ran the below test case on a PC to simulate 100 sessions calling the function at the same time.  Even with 100 sessions, oracle.exe used less than 1% of the CPU.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION slow_function (
  p_in INT) RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOCK.sleep(p_in);
  RETURN 1;
END;
/

select /*+ parallel(100) */ slow_function(60) from dba_tables;

--In another session, check that statement is really using 100 sessions.
select * from v$px_process;
```